# SQL find parent where children match over multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database where one `user` has multiple `submission` and one `submission` has multiple `post`

I would like to find all users who have made posts with the tag "car" **and** posts with the tag "bike".

Following is the query I tried which won't work since it looks for a single post with the tag "car" and "bike"

```
select distinct u.*
from users u
         inner join submission s on u.name = s.user_name
         inner join post rp on s.id = rp.submission_id
where rp.tag = 'card' and rp.tag = 'bike'
```

How would I structure this query correctly so it returns the users who have made posts with the tag "car" and posts with the tag "bike"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need  only the name you could try checking for the user with count distinct  = and tag = card  or tag = bike

```
select  u.name 
from  users 
inner join submission s on u.name = s.user_name
inner join post rp on s.id = rp.submission_id
where rp.tag = 'car' OR rp.tag = 'bike'
group by u.name 
having count(distinct  rp.tag) = 2
```

if you need all the user info you should join this result with users

```
select u.*
from users u 
inner  join  (
  select  u.name 
  from  users 
  inner join submission s on u.name = s.user_name
  inner join post rp on s.id = rp.submission_id
  where rp.tag = 'car' OR rp.tag = 'bike'
  group by u.name 
  having count(distinct  rp.tag) = 2 
) t on t.name  = u.name
```